# Certain sIFR Selectors not working in Safari--extremely unusual bug:

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, safari, sifr

I am creating a site, CardinalCoffee.com, using sIFR.

It's not quite ready to go, so access by adding

```
72.249.85.228   cardinalcoffee.com
72.249.85.228   www.cardinalcoffee.com
```

to your /etc/hosts (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows).

On the blog page (http://cardinalcoffee.com/blog/), and only on the blog page, certain sIFR selectors fail--but only in Safari. 
The sIFR-based navigation and blog post subheadings don't show up on the blog page, but they do every where else (and on all other browsers the /blog/ page is fine).

Here are the pertinent selectors from sifr-config.js:

```
sIFR.replace(itc_anna_std, {
  selector: '#top_nav li a',
    css: [
        '.sIFR-root {.sIFR-root { background-color: #f8eca8; color: #FFBF11; }',
        'a { text-decoration: none; color: #FFBF11;}',
        'a:link { color: #FFBF11; color: #FFBF11;}',
        'a:hover { color: #FFBF11; color: #FFBF11;}'
    ],
    wmode: 'transparent',
    forceSingleLine: true,
    tuneWidth: 2
});
sIFR.replace(itc_anna_std, {
  selector: '.non-admin #content_column .entry h2 a',
  css: [
        '.sIFR-root { background-color: #f8eca8; color: #170504; text-align:left;}',
        'a {text-decoration:none; color: #170504;}',
        'a:hover { color: #170504; }'       
    ],
    wmode: 'transparent',
    tuneHeight: -18,
    offsetTop: -6
});
```

Additionally, the font-size declaration on Subheadings (selector: **.entry h2 a**) seems to be ignored. Here is the pertinent style rule from sifr.css:

```
    .sIFR-active .non_admin #content_column .entry h2 {
        font-size: 36px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
```

This is a WordPress site.

[edit]:
Appears that this rule is to blame somehow:

```
sIFR.replace(itc_anna_std, {
  selector: '.non-admin #content-column .entry h2',
  css: [
        '.sIFR-root { background-color: #f8eca8; color: #170504;}',
        'a { text-decoration: none; color: #170504;}',
        'a:link { text-decoration: none; color: #170504;}',
        'a:hover { color: #170504;}'
    ],
    wmode: 'transparent',
    tuneHeight: -18,
    offsetTop: -6
});
```

(I moved the other sIFR replace to the top of the file and the navigation began to load flawlessly.)

Comment: I appreciate your insightful comment! 

But the navigation must be generated dynamically, and managing ImageMagick + Wordpress, confounded by the necessities of image transparency over a complex background are just absurd in complexity, compared to an albeit vexing sIFR bug.

Hopefully my resolution will be of some value to other developers employing sIFR.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, looks like the fact that there was a class assigned to the <a> inside each <h2> because I was enabling an edit-in-place function with Flutter.

When I removed the class on the <a>, the replacements came through just fine.

Still doesn't explain why moving the **header div.SimpleSideNav ul.sf li** sIFR replacement to the top of the sifr-config.js configurations made it work, but I'm not going to look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: Not sure, but looks like you figured it out :) It is possible that there were issues regarding selector specificity. sIFR requires you to put the most specific replacements first.

BTW, you can't replace links directly, they won't work properly cross-browser. You need to replace their parent element so the link ends up inside the Flash movie.